# Convert IETF date format to shorter one using jquery

Tags: jquery, date

i have a long string of date .
looks like that : Mon Jun 18 2012 19:00:00 . 
my question is simple.
i want it to be shows like this : dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm (HH implament for 24 hours )
im using jQuery and all its UI.
please dont tell me to add this Date.js class. it can be done by simple jQuery for sure :)
Thank You !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have jQueryUI loaded there is a full date formatting utilty built in but it doesn't handle time. Beyond that you need to work with native javscript Date object yourself or use a data library like date.js to simplify parsing.

Example using jQUeryUI: http://jsfiddle.net/qqLMd/

```
 var newDate=$.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', new Date('Mon Jun 18 2012 19:00:00');
```

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate

Your assuredness that this was a simple jQUery process was misconceived. jQuery doesn not have any date handling in core API

[MDN DATE Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: question, if i have this date i want to chage in a var, can i just write it down there?

Comment: it works, i ment like :  var newDate=$.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', new Date(someLongDate);

Comment: but only one problem..im having problem creating something like dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm

Comment: I already explained that time is not included in formatting. You could use a combination of both answers

Comment: Here's a fiddle using both answers. Code is much shorter  http://jsfiddle.net/qqLMd/1/

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use the substring() method.

```
var longDate = 'Mon Jun 18 2012 19:00:00';

var date = longDate.substring(8,10);
var month = longDate.substring(4,7);
var year = longDate.substring(11,15);
var hours = longDate.substring(16,18);
var minutes = longDate.substring(19,21);

if(month == "Jan")
    month = "01";
else if(month == "Feb")
    month = "02";
else if(month == "Mar")
    month = "03";
else if(month == "Apr")
    month = "04";
else if(month == "May")
    month = "05";
else if(month == "Jun")
    month = "06";
else if(month == "Jul")
    month = "07";
else if(month == "Aug")
    month = "08";
else if(month == "Sep")
    month = "09";
else if(month == "Oct")
    month = "10";
else if(month == "Nov")
    month = "11";
else if(month == "Dec")
    month = "12";

var oriDate = date + "/" + month + "/" + year + " ";
if(hours == 0)
    oriDate += "00:";
else
    oriDate += hours + ":";
if(minutes == 0)
    oriDate += "00";
else
    oriDate += minutes;

alert(oriDate); // 18/06/2012 19:00
```

Check the jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/reygonzales/v2tSb/

Comment: seems working, still its a very unefficient code. lots of Ifs and var creations.
seems like jQuery function can do it faster.

Comment: You can remove the var statements -- they're for legibility. You can also store the if/else values in a hash map with the 3-character string as a key. jQuery is a library on top of javascript so the date formatting functions there can't be so much better -- perhaps just more readable.